# getElementsByClassName is not working, but Id's work fine

Tags: getelementsbyclassname, clonenode

I am trying to get some elements by Class Name and it's not working. However, if I change to get element by ID, it works fine. Would like to understand why Class Name method is not working. 
Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kXmpY/2681/
If I change to ID's it works. What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="cloneLink">Click me</a>
<div class="duplicator"> 
<label for="newInput">Label</label>
<input type="text">
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("cloneLink").onclick = duplicate;

var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementsByClassName("duplicator");

function duplicate() {
var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
clone.id = "duplicator" + i++; // there can only be one element with 
an ID
original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementsByClassName returns a `HTMLCollection` instead of a single element.

You need to write

```
var original = document.getElementsByClassName("duplicator")[0];
```

That is if you have a single element with that classname you want to manipulate.

> The getElementsByClassName() method returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

Read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: That worked, not sure I understand it completely but will read up. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @user1898404 Added some more info

Answer (score 0):

[document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) will return an array like object called `HTMLCollection`. For your code to work you need to make sure that its length is greater than zero then access the elements and attach the event.

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("cloneLink");
if(elements.length){
  elements.forEach( element => element.addEventListener("click" , duplicate))
}
```

Comment: The arrow (=>) that is part of the forEach is not supported by IE. You'll have to do it the old-fashioned way for the time being, with a `for` loop.

Comment: @FrankConijn you got it a bit mixed up. the arrow function is the callback for the forEach. `Array#forEach` is IE9+ compatible. its also 2018 you can use a preprocessor if needed

Comment: Can you make a small working Codepen or Fiddle with your code?